# RealmSwift: storing an element with a timestamp

Tags: swift, generics, realm

I am trying to define a wrapper around objects I want to store in Realm. The wrapper should contain an additional date object so that I can filter old objects. So far I have this

```
public final class RealmDateTaggedRealmObject: ObjectFacade {
    @objc public dynamic var date: Date?
    @objc public dynamic var value: ObjectFacade?
    @objc private dynamic var id: String = ""

    public override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return #keyPath(id)
    }

    public convenience init<T: RealmMappable>(from object: RealmDateTagged<T>) {
        self.init()
        date = object.date
        value = object.value.asRealmObject
        id = object.primaryKey
    }
}
```

The `RealmMappable` protocol enables transforming implementing entities into `ObjectFacade`. The `ObjectFacade` class is an empty class that inherits from `Object`, because I got an exception if I declared

```
@objc public dynamic var value: Object?
```

So I tried to be smart and created `ObjectFacade`. Turns out I'm not so smart cause it always stores `nil`. Also, `value` can't be a generic type because it is not supported in Objective-C.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. What's an 'additional' date object as opposed to the 'first' date property? Why this `#keyPath(id)`? Generally speaking, #keyPath is just syntactic sugar that generates a string value. What's a `RealmDateTagged`? Can you maybe include an example use case of what you're trying to do? It would help clarify the question.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you are subclassing ObjectFacade in addition to defining it as a property